# What happens to the social policy of a conquered civilization?

Tags: civilization-5

I am playing against Elizabeth, where she had adopted a social policy that makes every other AI players and me lose the infl uence on the city states at a faster rate. I'm struggling with the budget, and also being hugely dependent on,the maritime CS allies for the extra food, Lizzy's social policy is really giving me a hard time.

Fortunately enough, however, I have a significant advantage in military tech over her and I managed to crush almost entirety of England with three more cities to go, which includes London.

If I conquer the English civ, will the previous social policy of Elizabeth be canceled out? If it is so, I am willing to conquer England at all costs. If it doesn't, then I most likely won't demolish the civ, for I am afraid to be denounced a warmonger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you fully conquer England, all social policies she enacted will be erased. Meaning in this case, your city state influence will degrade at the normal rate again instead of the accelerated rate. Keep in mind, other nations may have this policy, or if Greece is in the game you may still face similar effects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. Greece has been wiped out from the very beginning in my game, so my only concern for the time being was England. Offhand, do I have to fully conquer in order to nullify the AI's social policy? Taking down the capital city would not be enough, if I understand correctly?

Comment: You will need to fully conquer, as in, the AI will need to admit defeat via diplomacy dialogue. Conquering the capital city will just move it to another city, and the social policies will still exist.

Comment: Not so much erased as disabled. If a Civilization is brought back into a game (I think only human players can do this), I think they get their policies and science back.